# Removing margins from map plots

Tags: r, plot

I can't seem to remove the margins from plots of spatial objects. Solutions posted to other types of plots don't seem to work in this case.  Par's `mai` and `oma` arguments also fail.  Very grateful for advice.

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
bbox = cbind(c(179,179,-179,-179,179), c(89,-89,-89,89,89))

png('test.png', width=1000, height=500)
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0), oma=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(wrld_simpl, col='grey', bg='white', border=NA)
lines(bbox, col='red', lwd=3)
dev.off()
browseURL('test.png')
```

The red bounding box should plot just inside the graphical output border.

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit the code to make it reproducible?

Comment: Perhaps `par(mar=rep(0,4))`?

Comment: `library(maptools)` is what you need. Sorry mine loads automatically on startup..

Comment: I'm using SpatialDataFrames (maptools) and I'm not sure they're compatible with `map` are they?

Comment: Sorry, my remark was again on the reproducibility of your code (not a suggestion of solution). Where is the `map` variable defined?

Comment: Thanks for the lesson, but I DID try the script. That is actually how I noticed that I couldn't reproduce your example. By the way, the result of the command in the previous comment is: [1] "wrld_simpl". Is there any chance that there might be something missing in your code?

Comment: Ah that explains it. `map` should read `wrld_simpl`. I'm sorry - I'm hitting a deadline and doing multiple things right now. When I tested it it did work, because I also have an object called `map`..

Comment: @DWin the script error has been corrected

Comment: No the problem is real

Comment: Well then ... You need to explain better what problem remains. The map I created with that code does not look like what you posted and seems to adhere to your specification.

Comment: My toadiest apologies to everyone. I'll be sure to take extra care to double check my example code in future (note to self: always restart your R session first).

Comment: Strange how a genuine problem question with a demonstrable solution gets so many down-votes. Hey ho..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: this answer was rewritten on 9 March 2019 to demonstrate an issue with the data set. The plotting approach is still correct, but the output may not be what was desired.

---

I take your question to mean,

> how do I plotting a map so that there is no padding around the map
>   data in the output image file.

This means plotting the map figure with no margins around the plot. Another requirement will be to plot the map with correct aspect ratio and in a defined latitude and longitude range. For a world map we need from 90 north to 90 south, and from 180 West to 180 east.

```
require(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

# set up the output file
png('test.png', width=1200, height = 600, res = 300)

# define the plot and margins
par(ann = FALSE,
    bg = "white",
    bty = "n",
    mai = c(0,0,0,0),
    mgp = c(0, 0, 0),
    oma = c(0,0,0,0),
    omd = c(0,1,0,1),
    omi = c(0,0,0,0),
    usr = c(-180, 180, -90, 90),
    pin = c(4,2),
    plt = c(0,1,0,1),
    pty = "m",
    xaxs = 'i',
    xaxt = 'n',
    xpd = FALSE,
    yaxs = 'i',
    yaxt = 'n')
# plot the world map
plot(wrld_simpl,
     col='grey',
     bg='white',
     border=NA,
     ann=FALSE,
     axes = FALSE)
# plot points at extremes
par(new = TRUE)

plot(c(0,0,-180,180),c(90,-90,0,0), type = "p", col = "red",pch="+", cex=0.5)

dev.off()
browseURL('test.png')
```

The figure is defined to extend from the north to south poles, and to and from the anti-meridian. This is done using the usr... part of `par()`, where the graphic is set up.

To demonstrate the range of the plot relative to the edge of the graphic, I've added 4 red crosses. Those are at the north and south poles and at +/- 180 degrees along the equator, which was also where I set the limits of the plot.

The points show that the map is the right size east-west, and north-south. There is no land under the north pole, so that white area in the north is correct. It could look like a white border gap if one forgot about Arctic geography. But there is some white space in Antartica north of the south pole, which should be shown as land (and may have seemed to be a border around the image for some readers). I guess the fact there is no ocean or border that far south (and thus no need for a data point) causes trouble. I think the data in `wrld_simpl` could be adjusted to deal with that.

Another option would be to adjust `par()` so that the area plotted doesn't go as far south, but I'm not happy with that.

[image]

Comment: Although your image doesn't have margins on the sides, it still has margins on the top and bottom.

Comment: @rodrigo - sure? In the .PNG file there aren't any. There are the appearance of margins here because of the stackoverflow CSS, but that's just padding

Comment: I just dragged the image around. When I get home I'll save it to be sure.

Comment: ... and updated anyway because there's something screwy in the data. The plotting routine is fine, though.

Comment: Maybe you could try with different sources, such as [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_map_units.zip). I was having a similar problem after reprojecting a world map to Peirce Quincuncial, but it was solved after I corrected the bbox of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.